# Finding values in one column with several different values in another column

Tags: r

I have a large data set with a column for the identity and a birthdate. Unfortunately, some id names were used for different individuals.

```
sample <- 
    data.frame(id = c("val1", "val1", "val1", "val1", "val2", "val2", "val2", 
                      "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3"),
         birthday = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "7"))
```

Now I'm trying to find which id's have different birthdates to be able to rename them.

I know I could do it with a for loop but I was wondering whether there is an easier & faster way? Or how would you deal with it?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- rowSums(table(sample$id, sample$birthday) > 0)
names(x[x>1])

[1] "val2" "val3"
```

This means the `val2` and `val3` `id` have multiple birthdays.

Or: `aggregate(birthday ~ id, sample, function(x) length(unique(x)))` gives the amount of unique birthdays per id:

```
    id birthday
1 val1        1
2 val2        3
3 val3        3
```

Update: for your desired output I made sure `id` is of character type. You could do something like this:

```
sample$id <- as.character(sample$id)
x <- rowSums(table(sample$id, sample$birthday) > 0)
y <- sample$id %in% names(x[x>1]) 
sample[y,]$id <- paste0("NEW", sample[y,]$birthday)

sample

     id birthday
1  val1        1
2  val1        1
3  val1        1
4  val1        1
5  NEW2        2
6  NEW3        3
7  NEW4        4
8  NEW5        5
9  NEW6        6
10 NEW7        7
11 NEW7        7
```

Comment: thanks! Would you also use a for loop for the renaming of the variables?

Comment: Generally, I would aim to avoid using for loops in R. Could you give us a glimpse what your desired output looks like? And do you have the appropriate renaming values stored in a vector or dataframe already?

Comment: For the example above I would want something like this: 

'sampleNEW = data.frame("id" = c("val1", "val1", "val1", "val1", "NEW1", "NEW2", "NEW3", "NEW4", "NEW5", "NEW6", "NEW6"),
                    "birthday" = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "7"))'

It does not matter what the new names are, I just need to be able to identify them as newly generated names.

Comment: Please, ask a new question because making ids unique is a new requirement.